# black residue left at the bottom of bowl after eating honey bunches of oats

Tags: breakfast

When I was eating honey bunches of oats with milk the other day, I noticed a black powder-like substance at the bottom of my bowl. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Possibly very fine iron filings.  They use solid iron instead of dissolved iron when enriching, because it decreases spoilage.

Comment: Might be testable with a magnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the same black dust at the bottom of my bowl of Honey Bunches Of Oats and I just happened to have a small magnet nearby.  The magnet picked it right up!  I have heard of iron being in cereal like this but I don't know if it is a good thing or a bad thing.  We all need iron but is this they way to get it?  Not sure about that!

Comment: Hi Amy. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Answers on our site must directly address the question at hand. In the future, a discussion point like yours would be more appropriate to bring to our chat room or (maybe) as a comment on the original question. The reason we remove discussion is to maintain our strict Q&A format. It's a little different than other websites you may have used, but there's a method to the madness. :)

Comment: This seems to be saying that black powder may be iron, which sure seems like an answer to me.

Comment: If it is magnetic and supposed to be in food, it is iron - cobalt, nickel, steel, or engineered magnet alloys certainly do NOT belong in there, and anything else is not magnetic :)

Answer (score 2):

The company says that it is grain dust. Yes, I contacted them to ask when I found the same powder in my cereal. I've seen many, many different types of grain dust in my life, and none were anything like that black powder. Needless to say, I don't believe the given "explanation," so I stopped eating the cereal

Answer (score -2):

My daughter discovered some black residue with the bottom of her cereal bowl she brought it over to show me and used a magnet off the fridge and it was moving inside the bowl I think if they are adding this magnetic material of any kind it should be illegal they're getting away with using stuff that is cheaper for them to use than actually adding something of more natural value for for the body shame on this company we will not be buying any type of cereal products I assume that everything probably has a little of the stuff in it